# Check for background color or image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a blog theme which uses a mixture of featured images and featured colors when the writer publishes their post. I'd like to have the script run through three things:

1. Check if there is a featured image. If so, use that.
2. If there is no featured image, is there a featured color? If so, use that.
3. If neither are set, generate a random color.

I've got a snippet of JavaScript which *almost* works, and I think there may be a problem with the logic I'm using in the `if` statement.

**Script**

```
$(".post").each(function randomColor() {
        var bgCol = $(".post").css('backgroundColor');
        if ( bgCol != "rgb(0,0,0)" || (bgCol.attr('style').indexOf('image') !== -1 )) {
          var color = "#"+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
          $(this).css("background-color", color)
        }
        else { return }
      });
```

I set up a [jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/z2eyc79m/1/). It keeps the images, but overrides the featured color if it's set.

**Any thoughts on how I can improve the `if` loop?**

I have a demo (very sparse) of the [blog theme](http://dev.brianbennett.org/anchor) so you can see what I'm going for.

Comment: What is `none` supposed to be? There's no such keyword/native value in JavaScript. Did you mean the string literal `"none"`?

Comment: The default value for `background-image` in CSS (which I thought I was checking...) is `none`.

Comment: Yep, but it's the string value, not keyword. `none != "none"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/cetuvo/4/edit)**

I would check for the computed styles:

```
$(".post").each(function() {
  var cs = window.getComputedStyle(this);
  if (cs.backgroundImage==="none" &&
      cs.backgroundColor==="transparent" ||
      /0\)$/.test(cs.backgroundColor) ) {
    var color = "hsl("+ ~~(Math.random()*360) +",60%,70%)";     
    $(this).css("background-color", color);   
  }
});
```

This line `/0\)$/.test(cs.backgroundColor)` just tests if the `rgba` value ends with 0 alpha opacity `0)` (Webkit returns rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) instead of "transparent" which is basically the same).

Using `hsl()` *Hue, Saturation, Lightness* (instead of hex `#`) will give you more control over the random generated color intensity (so you can best suit it to the general website lightness and *feel*).

Comment: At the risk of demonstrating my ignorance, if there is **no** background attribute set for the class, do they compute as `transparent`? I tested this, and all the undefined divs are staying white.

Comment: @BrianBennett you're not ignorant :) it's just me with the bad habit of not testing my code in Chrome :) brb to you soon with a fix

Comment: It looks like Chrome applies `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. I'll have to check with Safari to see if it's a Webkit thing.

Comment: @BrianBennett Exactly, I was about to test and here you go with a quick fix: http://jsbin.com/cetuvo/2/edit

Comment: That did it :-) I wasn't familiar with `match` method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".post").each(function randomColor() {
        var bgCol = $(".post").css('backgroundColor');
        console.log(bgCol);
        if ( bgCol == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
          var color = "#"+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
          $(this).css("background-color", color)
        }
        else { return }
      });
```

Here is the code as all changes applied by css you need just look for element without background and generate random color.